# Read Stream on one thread and Write stream on another thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

In the following code, the messages from the server are received on one thread (inside `while loop`). And, the messages to the server are sent on main GUI thread (on `sendButton_Click`)

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace SimulatedClient
{
    public partial class ClientForm : Form
    {
        TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient();
        NetworkStream serverStream = default(NetworkStream);
        string readdata = null;

        public ClientForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void connectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            clientSocket.Connect(hostTextbox.Text, Int32.Parse(portTextBox.Text));

            Thread ctThread = new Thread(getMessages);
            ctThread.Start();
        }

        public void getMessages()
        {
            string returnData;

            while (true)
            {
                serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                var buffersize = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
                byte[] instream = new byte[buffersize];

                serverStream.Read(instream, 0, buffersize);
                returnData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(instream);
                readdata = returnData;

                UpdateReceivedPressureLabelText(readdata);
                //msg();
            }
        }

        void UpdateReceivedPressureLabelText(string value)
        {
            Action action = () => incomingTextBox.Text = value;
            this.Invoke(action);
        }

        //private void msg()
        //{

        //    if (this.InvokeRequired)
        //    {
        //        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(msg));

        //    }
        //    else
        //    {
        //        incomingTextBox.Text = readdata;
        //    }
        //}

        private void sendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] outstream = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(outgoingTextBox.Text);

            serverStream.Write(outstream, 0 , outstream.Length);
            serverStream.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**QUESTION:** Is it ok to do so i.e. is it ok to receive messages using one thread and send messages on another thread for the same `clientSocket`? The program is working but I am not sure if it could lead to some problem?

Comment: [Stream.Synchronized(Stream) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.synchronized). This method implies that the streams are not thread-safe.

Comment: ["Read and write operations can be performed simultaneously on an instance of the `NetworkStream` class without the need for synchronization. As long as there is one unique thread for the write operations and one unique thread for the read operations, there will be no cross-interference between read and write threads and no synchronization is required."](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream).

Comment: Sockets are [thread safe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket?view=netframework-4.8#thread-safety), I assume TcpClient (since it´s a wrappper around a socket) also is.

Comment: @C.Gonzalez That's a non sequitur. Just because Sockets _are_ thread safe, does not mean a wrapping component has to be. They may use buffers, queues, whatever that _do_ need additional measures to ensure thread safety.